# Getting This page isn't available error while sharing localhost page in Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to share my localhost page into facebook. But I am getting This page isn't available message.

I registered my app. Below are the details

App ID -  2129405327086578, 
App Domains - loachost ,
Site URL - http://localhost:56897

Below is my code

```html
<button id="shareonfacebook">ShareOnFaceBook</button>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#shareonfacebook').click(function (e) {e.preventDefault();
                FB.ui(
                    {
                        method: 'popup',
                        name: 'TestShare',
                        href: 'http://localhost:56897/MyPage?id=26',
                        caption: 'hey how is my Application ? ',
                        description: 'hey how is my Application ?',
                        message: ''
                    });
               });
            });
    </script>

    <script>
        FB.init({
            appId: '2129405327086578'
        });
    </script>
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: I don’t think it will run on localhost due to security imposes by FB, please try running it from a public domain..

Comment: This has nothing to do with security, Facebook simply can’t access your localhost … the “local” part of that isn’t just a _random_ combination of letters.

Answer (score 0):

Tt`s only possible if you have a static IP-adress, and in this case you have to write {your IP}:{port of localhost} to href field